# Is there any source to download German data set for crop disease incidences for last 20-50 years?

Tags: data-request, germany, disease

I am looking for the crop (especially grapes) disease incidence data set for Germany for the last 30 to 50 years, but I am not able to find it.
Does anyone know of any data source?